# How to convert items database to links on a website using Php and Sql

Tags: php

I am working on a website created with PHP & SQL.
The sql data base has two columns "reference no" & "tracking no".

Now, the problem I have is when a user searches reference no I am to display tracking no but I am unable create a link on which the user may click to check the latest details regarding his order.

The kind of link required is mentioned below, where TRACKING_NO changes for every order

http://www.XYZ.com/content/in/en/express/tracking.shtml?brand=xyz&AWB=TRACKING_NO%0D%0A

Any help in resolving the problem will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So your question is how to connect strings in PHP and echo it? Please provide more information or I will have to flag this.

Comment: please take a look. I have updated the information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be something like this:

```
<a href="http://www.xyz.com/content/in/en/express/tracking.shtml?brand=xyz&AWB=<?php echo  $trackingcode ?>">Your link</a>
```

where `$trackingcode` is coming from your sql

Comment: thanks for the answer but will the trackingcode update it self for every result ? Please dont mind it this sounds silly as I do not have any web development experience

Comment: You are extracting the information from the database example using `mysql_connect(SELECT trackingNO from table WHERE whatever=whatever)`, then populate the `$trackingcode` from the record that is returned from your database.

Comment: thanks for the update but where do I enter the above sql query ? Do I insert it in the HTML code ?

Comment: Yes - I suggest you have a look at the manual - http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Comment: Thanks for the above link, I am using Dreamweaver to handle the coding part

Comment: If you are using php, then you need to connect to the database and get the tracking code that you wish to display in the url. Once you get it using `mysql_connect()`, then it is a matter of displaying it using the method I mentioned above.

Comment: I have a search & result page made using php. I am able to display results on the result page from the database but what now ? Request you to please help out a little more

Comment: You will have to provide more information. Do you need to display the tracking code on the result page? If yes, then get the tracking code from the database as well and display it in your html.

Comment: this is what i have done till now http://sunenterprises.hostei.com/search.php when a user searches for example 123456 the tracking no is displayed. Now where & how do I put the info provided by you to get a url as listed above in my post which shows further result. Thanks

Comment: so once the user carries that search, where do you wish to display that link? You can get the **123456** by using `$_GET["searchinput"]` which can be displayed anywhere you want including the a link.

Comment: by using $_GET["searchinput"] I get the whatever the user has searched for but I am unable to get the actual tracking no from reference no by writing echo $_GET["tracking no"] at the same time I also get an error of undefined index

Comment: How can I pass the value retrieved by the search page to a variable so that I can use it in search URL

Comment: At this stage the answer to your has been provided and you have resolved your problem.  If you wish to ask something else, best if you open another question. It would also be nice if you indicate that you have accepted an answer. Also I suggest you add more information on what you have done so far and what you wish to achieve.